# Captures or capture the imagination

Tags: grammar

Which of these two sentences is the correct one please?

"[Store X is] the preferred place to shop for unique decor items that **capture** the imaginations of children"

or

"[Store X is] the preferred place to shop for unique decor items that **captures** the imaginations of children"

**EDIT:**

The decor items being the item that capture the imagination of children.

Comment: Why would this be off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What captures the children's imagination? The place to shop? Or the decor items? This will dictate whether you'll have to use the singular or the plural form of the verb.

Comment: Many thanks Louel! Will mark it correct as soon as Stack allows me to. Seems there is a delay.

Comment: So it's "capture" then, "decor items" being plural. :-)